# Convert multiple level array to single level array?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert this array

```
[[["b", "c"], ["c", "d"]], [["v", "e"], ["r", "g"]]]
```

into

```
[["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["v", "e"], ["r", "g"]]
```

How can I convert this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Array#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) takes an optional *level*:

> The optional `level` argument determines the level of recursion to flatten

**Example:**

```
[[["b", "c"], ["c", "d"]], [["v", "e"], ["r", "g"]]].flatten(1)
#=> => [["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["v", "e"], ["r", "g"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []
a = [[["b", "c"], ["c", "d"]], [["v", "e"], ["r", "g"]]]
a.map{|x| x.map{|y| arr << y}}
puts arr
```